# SQLCipher iOS OpenSSL Build error: line 66: ./config: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, openssl, sqlcipher

When I'm trying to build an iOS project on my machine the build fails with the following error message:
"line 66: ./config: No such file or directory"

On other machines the build just runs without any problems. I'm using XCode 4.6.3 and my OpenSSL Path is set in the configuration. XCode commandline tools are also installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem simply was the path to the OpenSSL directory (/My Directory/openssl1.0.1e). The path contained whitespaces and although I put the path in quotes ("/My Directory/openssl1.0.1e" the project didn't compile. The final (and only solution in my case) was to rename the directory path to NOT contain whitespaces(/MyDirectory/openssl1.0.1e).

Answer (score 1):

To other trespassers. Just want to help people for a problem which had drove me nuts. Though this question already have a accepted answer i will provide my findings

I believe you should have followed the steps from [here](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/)

1. Make sure that there is no white spaces in the any of the values in the SourceTree of Xcode preference(Setting name, Display Name and Path). Double check and triple check. This is where a lot of people make mistake
2. Make sure the Xcode should have the name in Applications as Xcode not Xcode5.1.1 or something like that. It should be exactly Xcode.
3. Just the build the openssl separately and see, if you find the error then mostly error is in 1 & and 2 If not the error lies in Build Settings of your app. Check for header search paths, Flags as mentioned in above link
4. If problem persists for running in 64 bit devices then use this [sqlcipher project](https://github.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipherSpeed)