# Shell Script invocation error in xcode 5

Tags: ios, openssl, xcode5, sqlcipher

I am using openssl and sqlcipher in my project. I have to upgrade from Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5, but I compile project in Xcode 5 it gives me error cp: libCrypto.a No such file or directory, Cp:libssl.a No such file or directory

Shell Script invocation error

When I checked 'openssl-1.0.0e' folder the files get deleted when I clean or build in Xcode 5, it doesn't happen in Xcode 4.6 and work successfully.

I also tried by upgrading to version 'openssl-1.0.1f' and the updated sqlcipher function, but the error still remains

My projects architecture is $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Let me know if you need some more info.
Please help.

Comment: May be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974484/sqlcipher-ios-openssl-build-error-line-66-config-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @iPatel There is no space in the name of my directory.

Comment: I haven't work ever on Shell Script, i just want to help you .. so i just put this url otherwise i dnt kn abt it .. Thanks :) all D Best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was first downloded the project
https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

These project was not built when Xcode 5 was in different location from default location, so for these project to build it has xcode 5 has to be in default location. Then I ran the file build-libssl.sh in terminal. It runs successfully only when xcode 5 is in default location. When the script runs successfully then libssl.a and libcrypto.a files are made. I directly included them in frameworks section of project. I removed the older sqlcipher and openssl projects and only included the files in 'include' directory of downloaded project and in sqlcipher sqlite3.c,sqlite3.h, and sqlite3ext.h files. Now there was no need of that two projects, and it built successfully in xcode 5 project.

Answer (score 1):

> cp: libCrypto.a No such file or directory,

Linux file systems are case sensitive. Use `libcrypto.a`, not `libCrypto.a`.

> Cp:libssl.a No such file or directory

Same issue here. Use `cp`, not `Cp`.