# AllJoyn sample app Build failed on Xcode

Tags: xcode, alljoyn

I want to test AllJoyn chat app but following official step-by-step documentation https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat/ios-osx where first step is "Build a sample" and instructions are https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx
All goes fine until step:
**Build the samples**

*Open each of the following sample iOS applications in Xcode and build them by selecting Project > Build from the Xcode menu.*

*alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/*

I opened /Users/piran/Documents/alljoyn/alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/BasicClient/BasicClient.xcodeproj in Xcode and trying **Product->Build** 
this fails with error `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

```
Ld /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BasicClient.app/BasicClient normal i386
    cd /Users/piran/Documents/alljoyn/alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/BasicClient
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/piran/Documents/alljoyn/alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/BasicClient/../../../../build/darwin/i386/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib -L/Users/piran/Documents/alljoyn/alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/BasicClient/../../../../build/darwin/arm/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib -F/Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Intermediates/BasicClient.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BasicClient.build/Objects-normal/i386/BasicClient.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lalljoyn -lajrouter -lBundledRouter.o -lssl -lcrypto -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -framework SystemConfiguration -lstdc++.6 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Intermediates/BasicClient.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BasicClient.build/Objects-normal/i386/BasicClient_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BasicClient-hawoulujhrgmpnfbxiryzpjkiasq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BasicClient.app/BasicClient
```

This error happens on each sample project build attempt. 
Am I missing something or have to do some additional steps to make it work?

Xcode 7.2.1

osX 10.11.3

Answer (score 1):

The link below gives instructions instructions on how to make sure OpenSSL is available to Xcode by setting the OPENSSL_ROOT environment variable. It is in the 'Obtaining OpenSSL' section:

https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx/build-source

Comment: Building openssl project gives another error 
`+ cp libcrypto.a /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openssl-eeuxsjkfqmnklucqsdxteshwmkir/Build/Intermediates/openssl.build/Debug-iphoneos/armv7-libcrypto.a
cp: libcrypto.a: No such file or directory
+ cp libssl.a /Users/piran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openssl-eeuxsjkfqmnklucqsdxteshwmkir/Build/Intermediates/openssl.build/Debug-iphoneos/armv7-libssl.a
cp: libssl.a: No such file or directory`

Comment: did you build openssl for armv7?

Comment: @MykolaTkachenko a quick search on "cp: libcrypto.a: No such file or directory" turned up a number of results, such as spaces in directory names causing problems. You might check that, or as Ry Jones mentioned you might check that you're building for the correct target. If those don't work here's another StackOverflow thread that may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480046/shell-script-invocation-error-in-xcode-5

Comment: All steps from  'Obtaining OpenSSL' are passed successfully. But the problem from question is still not solved and having same error.